# chart.js 2.3 dynamically load pie chart data

Tags: jquery, charts

I have a pie chart that want to be able toggle between MTD and YTD data. The chart to load fine on page load. I'm having difficulty changing the data via AJAX from MTD to YTD.

I've looked at many post regarding this but everything I've found is for an older version of chart.js 1.0.1.

I want to use the latest version (chart.js 2.3). Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-responsive">
   <canvas id="myPieChart" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var pieconfig = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [<cfoutput>#valueList(myPieData.totalAmt)#</cfoutput>], // the returned data looks like this (1254.52,223.50,etc.)
      backgroundColor: [
        "#F7464A",
        "#46BFBD",
        "#FDB45C",
        "#949FB1",
        "#4D5360",
        "#60A2C9",
        "#00A65A",
        "#D2D6DE",
        "#4D5360",
        "#00C0EF"
      ],
      label: 'Dataset 1'
    }],
    labels: [
      <cfoutput>#ListQualify(valueList(myPieData.busUnit), "'",  ",")#</cfoutput> // the returned label looks like this ('Joe','Jim',etc.)
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext("2d");    
  myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, pieconfig);
};
```

The above code works fine on page load. Below is my code to update the data in my pie chart.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/main/piechartdata/",
  data: {'workList':'sale','rtype':$rType},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(rData) {
    console.log(rData.labels);
    locData = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: rData.datapoint // return data looks like this: 4469.37,2455153.58,672038.48,83.27,58821.22,36606.71
          backgroundColor: [
            "#F7464A",
            "#46BFBD",
            "#FDB45C",
            "#949FB1",
            "#4D5360",
            "#60A2C9",
            "#00A65A",
            "#D2D6DE",
            "#4D5360",
            "#00C0EF"
          backgroundColor: [
            "#F7464A",
            "#46BFBD",
            "#FDB45C",
            "#949FB1",
            "#4D5360",
            "#60A2C9",
            "#00A65A",
            "#D2D6DE",
            "#4D5360",
            "#00C0EF"
          ],
          label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: rData.labels //return data looks like this: 'CBS','CFM','CIA','Millennium','OTHER','Thrifty'
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
        },
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
        },
        animation: {
          animateScale: true,
          animateRotate: true
        }
      }
    };  
    
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext("2d");    
    myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, locData);

  }
});
```

This was my latest failed attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

If you are just updating data call update() after changing your data:

```
myDoughnut.data.datasets[0].data[11] = 300;
  myDoughnut.update();
```

[Update Chart](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/gwdYzr?editors=1010)

else, destroy your chart first with destroy() and reinitialize your chart:

```
myDoughnut.destroy();
myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, locData);
```

[Destroy Chart](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/zBXqYR?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you, for your response, I'm going to try to get this working with a pie chart. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Your codepen sample are great, however it demonstrate how toggling chart type. Sorry, if I didn't explain what i was trying to do clearly. I'm trying to replace the data. For example, said I have 2016 data display and want to now load 2015 data.

Comment: @user752746: It is the same logic, i.e. you should be able to destroy the chart with 2015 data and then recreate a new chart with 2016 data, you might also be able to do this with update, the pens are just some general examples of their use.

Comment: Keno, I was able to update the chart using your example above. Many thanks!

Comment: I was able to get the random test data (i.e [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]) to work. I having trouble get the AJAX returned data (125.25,145.00,352.00) to populate the chart. Looking at the pieconfig I notice that it wrapped my entire data (“125.25,145.00,352.00”) string in double quote.

Comment: Here is update ajax call:
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/main/piechartdata/",
  data: {'workList':'sale','rtype':$rType},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(rData) {
    // return data rData.datapoint: 125.25,254.00,375.25
    pieconfig.data.datasets[0].data = [rData.datapoint];
    window.myDoughnut.update();
    console.log(pieconfig);

  }
});
Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to get it to work after by the common delimited string to and array like so rData.datapoint.split(',');.

Answer (score 5):

Keno's answer is accurate, I'll expand upon it a bit here:

You already have a chart object called myDoughnut here, and like any javascript object, you can access any of it's members, similar to a class in a traditional oop language.

In your case, after creating locData, you should be able to use:

```
myDoughnut.data = locData;
myDoughnut.update();
```

Instead of creating a new chart, you're just replacing the data in the existing chart with new data. You have to call update() in order for the changes to occur.

Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Brett, thank you for elaborating on Keno's response. This is the first time working with chart.js so it's your response definitely helps. Thanks again.